# How can I change size of circle in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

How can I change size of circle in first window, using slider from second window. Is there an option to send value from slider to first window and put this value in painter.drawEllipse fuction?
[image]

```
class ThirdWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        sld.setRange(0, 100)
        sld.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        sld.setPageStep(5)

        sld.valueChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)

        self.label = QLabel('0', self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setMinimumWidth(80)

        hbox.addWidget(sld)
        hbox.addSpacing(15)
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(600, 60, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('QSlider')
        self.show()

    def updateLabel(self, value):
        self.label.setText(str(value))

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialogi")
        self.w = ThirdWindow()
        actionFile = self.menuBar().addMenu("Dialog")
        action = actionFile.addAction("Zmień tło")
        action1 = actionFile.addAction("Zmień grubość koła")
        action1.triggered.connect(self.w.show)
        self.setGeometry(100, 60, 300, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: Green")


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.gray,  8, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawEllipse(100, 100, 100, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate with the parent class (in this case the class where the circle is located i.e. `Window` by calling `self.parentWidget()`

so you can call that inside your `updateLabel function` and pass the value. However to repaint the surface you must have a variable initiated in the main `Window`

Hence your code should look like-

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialogi")
        self.w = ThirdWindow()
        actionFile = self.menuBar().addMenu("Dialog")
        action = actionFile.addAction("Zmień tło")
        action1 = actionFile.addAction("Zmień grubość koła")
        action1.triggered.connect(self.w.show)
        self.setGeometry(100, 60, 300, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: Green")
        self.radius = 100 #add a variable radius to keep track of the circle radius

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.gray,  8, Qt.SolidLine))
        #change function to include radius
        painter.drawEllipse(100, 100, self.radius, self.radius)
```

and in the other widget change the `updateLabel` function to change the radius and call repaint

```
class ThirdWindow(QWidget):
        def updateLabel(self, value):
            self.label.setText(str(value))
            self.parentWidget().radius = value
            self.parentWidget().repaint()
```

Comment: after I made this changes in my code, my program is closing with error after using the slider, do you know what can be wrong in this code? This is code after using your clues https://justpaste.it/9luoo